# How to make two scrollviews linked in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I want to make a header-fixed table. The idea I have now is using two ScrollView, one for the header (RowLayout), one for the body (GridLayout). Is there any simple way to link these two on horizontal direction, so one scroll, the other scroll the same?

Comment: What's wrong with the `TableView`?

Comment: @Velkan, hi, I want to extend this to "first column as header" later.

Comment: btw. for future questions: It always helps to provide some code to play with, as it reduces the amount of work for an individual that might be able and possible even willing, to provide an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to do it with the [low-performing](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/06/10/qt-quick-controls-2-0-a-new-beginning/) `QtQuick.Controls 1.x`,
but the `QtQuick.Controls 2.0` `ScrollBar` has a property `position`.

So here, the trick is, to create two `ScrollBar`s, one for each Item to scroll, and bind the position of each to the position to the other one.

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 300
    height: 120
    title: qsTr("Hello World")


    Column {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Flickable {
            id: flick1
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height / 2
            contentHeight: 2 * height
            contentWidth: 2 * width
            Item {
                anchors.fill: parent
                Rectangle {
                    width: parent.height
                    height: parent.width
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    rotation: 90

                    gradient: Gradient {
                        GradientStop { position: 1; color: 'black' }
                        GradientStop { position: 0; color: 'white' }
                    }
                }
            }

            ScrollBar.horizontal: scrl1
        }
        Flickable {
            id: flick2
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height / 2
            contentHeight: 2 * height
            contentWidth: 2 * width
            clip: true

            Item {
                anchors.fill: parent
                Rectangle {
                    width: parent.height
                    height: parent.width
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    rotation: 90

                    gradient: Gradient {
                        GradientStop { position: 0; color: 'black' }
                        GradientStop { position: 1; color: 'white' }
                    }
                }
            }

            ScrollBar.horizontal: scrl2
        }
    }


    ScrollBar {
        id: scrl1
        orientation: Qt.Horizontal
    }

    ScrollBar {
        id: scrl2
        orientation: Qt.Horizontal
    }

    Binding {
        target: scrl2
        property: 'position'
        value: scrl1.position
    }
    Binding {
        target: scrl1
        property: 'position'
        value: scrl2.position
    }
}
```

How to attach `ScrollBar`s to almost anything, you can find in the answer to this question. I do not work with `Layouts` so, I can't be more specific on them.

[how to create a scrollbar for rectangle in QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40446017/how-to-create-a-scrollbar-for-rectangle-in-qml/40447091#40447091)

Comment: Even if there is a new version, QtQC 1 are not deprecated AFAIK

Comment: Ok, that was a bit polemic. But I guess you can say, it is recommended to not use them for performance reasons?

Comment: I guess they still offer native look on desktop software where QQC2 don't, but yes QQC2 are more performant, especially for embedded platforms.

Comment: Most importantly they are not maintained any more. No official maintainer is listed in the modules page. So yeah, consider them deprecated.